# TimeDistributed layer, but with different weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to apply a separate convolution to each layer of a 3-dimensional array, which brought me to the Keras TimeDistributed layer. But the documentation notes that:

> "Because TimeDistributed applies the same instance of Conv2D to each of the
> timestamps, the same set of weights are used at each timestamp."

However, I want to perform a separate convolution (with independently defined weights / filters) for each layer of the array, not using the same set of weights. Is there some built in way to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide your existing code or an example?

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to provide an example -- I'm still in the research phase here of how to do this so I don't have any code yet. Let's say I have an 100 x 50 x 50 matrix, and I want to run a separate convolution for each 100 2D array of size (50,50), but I want to train weights on each layer independently because each will contain different features (not actually) using time series data. Does that help clarify?